# How can i scrape the contents of the chrome address bar in c++?

Tags: c++, google-chrome

I am writing a program that needs to log what program is active and what website it is accessing if it is a browser.  I have the code that will grab the contents of the address bar window in IE, but I when I use winspy on chrome it all comes back as one window.  Does anyone know if there is a way to scrape the contents of the address bar?

The code that I have working for IE is:

```
HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
HWND hwndEdit = FindWindowEx(foreground, NULL, "EDIT", NULL);

HWND handle = FindWindowEx(foreground, NULL, "WorkerW", "Navigation Bar");
if (NULL != handle)
{
handle = FindWindowEx(handle, NULL, "ReBarWindow32", NULL);
if (NULL != handle)
{
handle = FindWindowEx(handle, NULL, "Address Band Root", NULL);
}}
HWND hwndEdit = FindWindowEx(handle, NULL, "Edit", NULL);

const int bufferSize = 5024;
Char textBuffer[bufferSize] = "";
SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)bufferSize, (LPARAM)textBuffer);

string addressbartext = textBuffer;
if(addressbartext == "AutoCompleteProxy")
{addressbartext = "";}
else
{addressbartext = textBuffer;
}

cout << addressbartext;
```

Comment: Most controls in chrome are actually implemented client side (e.g there is no correlating HWND/XID handle to them).

Comment: @CasperVonB is there another way I could grab this information then?

Comment: Try `FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, 'Chrome_OmniboxView', None)` I am not 100% sure if the omnibox is a native control or completely client side.

Comment: @CasperVonB Unfortunately this does not work. I probably need to use a different method, but I seem to be stuck on this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like chrome processes communicate via Named Pipes. http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication might help, although I'm not sure this protocol is open to calls from outside the browser.